# What does a linear equation with more than 2 variables represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

A linear equation with 2 variables, say $Ax+By+C = 0$, represents a line on a plane but what does a linear equation with 3 variables $Ax+By+Dz+c=0$ represent? A line in space, or something else?

On a general note, what does a linear equation with $n$ variables represent?

Comment: An equation $Ax+By+Dz+c=0$ (where $A,B,D$ are not all $0$) represents a plane in the space. More generally, an equation $A_1x_1+A_2x_2+\cdots+A_nx_n=B$, with the $n$ variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, where not all $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are zero, represents a $n-1$-dimensional space inside a $n$-dimensional space (usually called an [Affine Hyperplane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane#Affine_hyperplanes)). This is a kind of object that commonly appears when one is studying Linear Algebra. There are several generalizations, in several different directions, to this kind of object.

Comment: Some Wikipedia links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry#Lines_and_planes and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane

Answer (score 3):

In Geometry: the linear equation: $Ax+By+Dz+c=0$ in three variables $x$, $y$ & $z$ generally represents a plane in 3-D co-ordinate system having three orthogonal axes X, Y & Z.

The constants $A$, $B$, $D$ shows the $\color{#0ae}{\text{direction ratios}}$ of the vector normal to the plane: $Ax+By+Dz+c=0$. Its direction cosines are given as $$\cos\alpha=\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+D^2}}, \quad\cos\beta=\frac{B} {\sqrt{A^2+B^2+D^2}} \quad \text{&} \quad\cos\gamma=\frac{D}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+D^2}}$$

It can also be written in the $\color{#0ae} {\text{intercept form}}$ as follows $$\frac{x}{\left(\frac{-c}{A}\right)}+\frac{y}{\left(\frac{-c}{B}\right)}+\frac{z}{\left(\frac{-c}{D}\right)}=1$$ Where, $\left(\frac{-c}{A}\right)$, $\left(\frac{-c}{B}\right)$ & $\left(\frac{-c}{D}\right)$ are the intercepts of the plane with three orthogonal axes x, y & z respectively in the space.

In Linear Algebra: the linear equation: $Ax+By+Dz+c=0$ represents one of the three linear equations of a system having unique solution, infinite solutions or no solution.